# Divide all elements in row with the max value in row - Faster approach

Tags: r

I need to scale a `dataframe`.
The process I need to follow is the following:

> Divide all elements in a row with the max number in that row, unless that row contains number 1

I use this approach:

```
post_df <- df # original dataframe
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (! 1 %in% df[i,]) {
        post_df[i,] <- df[i,]/max(df[i,])
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a faster approach that will cut down some seconds because I run this in a big dataframe `86000 rows *500 cols` .

E.g

## 5 rows, 5 cols

Row 1: Divide all elements with 0.7
Row 2: Divide all elements with 0.4
Row 3: Ignore
Row 4: Ignore
Row 5: Ignore
[image]

Comment: Without sample data, it is difficult to understand what you mean by 'contains number 1'. And in general, one should avoid processing every single element like you are doing. Use vector operations.

Comment: Give me a second I will give an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description, we need to only `scale` those rows that doesn't have 1. Create a logical index ('i1') based on `rowSums` and then subset the dataset using 'i1', get the `max` of each row with `pmax`, divide with the subset and assign it back to the subset

```
i1 <- !rowSums(df==1)>0
df[i1,] <- df[i1,]/do.call(pmax, df[i1,])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:8, 10*5, replace = TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: Thank you all, akrun's approach was the fastest

Answer (score 1):

Example data: Only the first two rows have 1's in them.

```
df <- iris[1:5, 1:4]
df[2,3] <- 1
df[1,1] <- 1
df

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          1.0         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.0         0.2
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
```

Compute

```
res <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) if(any(df[x, ] == 1)) {
  df[x, ]
} else {
  df[x, ]/ max(df[x, ])
 }
)

t(res)


# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  1            3.5         1.4          0.2
#  4.9          3           1            0.2
#  1            0.6808511   0.2765957    0.04255319
#  1            0.673913    0.326087     0.04347826
#  1            0.72        0.28         0.04
```

Except the rows with 1's, rest were divided by the max of that row.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following

```
set.seed(2017)
# Sample data
mat <- matrix(sample(5*10), ncol = 5)
mat;
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   47   49   42   46   11
# [2,]   27    1   41   38   37
# [3,]   23   39   40   28   13
# [4,]   14   16   21    4   43
# [5,]   36   18    6   33    9
# [6,]   35   50   48   10   29
# [7,]    2   45   15   22    7
# [8,]   19   24    8   34    5
# [9,]   20   31   44    3   25
#[10,]   12   26   32   30   17


# Scale by row length if row does not contain 1
mat.scaled <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) if (1 %in% x) x else x / length(x)))
mat.scaled;
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]  9.4  9.8  8.4  9.2  2.2
# [2,] 27.0  1.0 41.0 38.0 37.0
# [3,]  4.6  7.8  8.0  5.6  2.6
# [4,]  2.8  3.2  4.2  0.8  8.6
# [5,]  7.2  3.6  1.2  6.6  1.8
# [6,]  7.0 10.0  9.6  2.0  5.8
# [7,]  0.4  9.0  3.0  4.4  1.4
# [8,]  3.8  4.8  1.6  6.8  1.0
# [9,]  4.0  6.2  8.8  0.6  5.0
#[10,]  2.4  5.2  6.4  6.0  3.4
```